# Как активировать функцию после ввода символа @?

Tags: javascript

Как активировать определённую функцию только после того как в определённое поле input введём символ @ ? Если такое вообще реально. Спасибо.

Comment: реально конечно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это будет самый простой пример, но возможностей для кастомизации и каких-то особых кейсов полным полно)

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

const invokeMeAfterSymbol = () => {
  console.log('You input @');
}

input.oninput = event => {
  const {value} = input;
  if(value[value.length - 1] === '@') {
    // Здесь вызываем вашу функцию
    invokeMeAfterSymbol();
  }
}
```

```html
<input id='input'>
```

Comment: Зачем использовать конструкции когда есть регулярки?

Comment: что может быть общего между const и oninput ? Да еще и деструкторизация в придачу.

Answer (score 3):

```js
 document.querySelector('.input')
    .addEventListener('input', (e)=> {
        const t = e.target;
        /\@/.test(t.value) && alert('true')
    }, false)
```

```html
<input class="input" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял то что-то подобное:

JS

```
function inputHandler (event){
  let q = event.target.value;
  return q.indexOf('@') > -1;
}
```

HTML

```
<input onchange='inputHandler()'/>
```

Возвращает boolean если `@` в input

Comment: если ввести в поле строку _string@_ то уже ничего не сработает

Comment: работает, проверил

Comment: `Возвращает boolean если @ в input`, нет, вернет `true`, только если `value` РАВНО `@`, если там есть еще какие-то символы, то будет возвращать `false` https://jsbin.com/yejiduwaki/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Ну да так и есть

Comment: А да не правильно понял.

Comment: Поправил, теперь ок